# $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ is $T$-cyclic if $W_1, W_2$ are $T$-cyclic with minimal polynomials relatively prime

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T:V \rightarrow V$ linear operator. Suppose that $W_i=F[T]v_i$ is a $T$-cyclic subspace and the minimal polynomial $q_i={q_T}|_{W_i}$ for $i=1,2$. Suppose that $q_1, q_2$ are relatively prime and $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. Show that $V$ is $T$-cyclic.

To prove that $V$ is $T$-cyclic, I want to find a cyclic vector $v$ such that $F[T]v=V$. My instinct tells me that $v=v_1+v_2$ is the cyclic vector. Since $F[T](v_1+v_2)=F[T]v_1+F[T]v_2$, which corresponds to the structure $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. But I don't know how to show that this is the whole space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea looks good. We know that given any $w_j$, we can find a polynomial $p_j$ so that $p_j(T)v_j=w_j$, and we now need to satisfy two such conditions simultaneously. For this, it's enough to find a $p$ with $p\equiv p_j\bmod q_j$, and this is possible by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_principal_ideal_domains)